# Possible to play stereo sound through single speaker?

Tags: macos, audio, sound-volume

Here's my situation: I have a Klipsch Promedia 2.1 system and the left channel died. The left speaker works fine when plugged in the right speaker output on the sub. Right now I have both speaker wires in the right speaker output in the sub so I get the right channel on the L and R speakers. Is it possible to play both the left and right channels on the iMac through the right channel so I at least hear everything from both channels?

Comment: What types of input to the klipsch system are available to you?

Comment: It only has the 3.5mm TRS input that plugs into the iMac's headphone jack.

Comment: Got it - so you need a software mix down to the rear microphone jack or hardware external to the mac to do the mixing of the channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Universal Access option to do this.

[image: In System Preferences - Universal Access]

Comment: Just what I needed! I tried Audio Hijack Pro and was able to get it mixing the channels, but this is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Open System Preferences > Sound > Output. There's a slider that allows you to change the balance between the left and right channels. Sliding it all the way to the right will play all the sound from the system through the right channel (essentially mono instead of stereo).

Comment: I'm not sure if that will scrap the left-hand channel's content though...

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as it doesn't mix the channels to the right side only, it just plays the right channel.

Comment: Ah, I see. Definitely was mistaken there. The Universal Access is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a mono 3.5mm audio cable, plug it in, you will have both output channels hard-mixed and played on both speakers.

If the cable on your speaker is non-removable, simply buy a 3 inch male-to-female one.

And if you can not find a cable like this, go to a shop that sells audio cables for guitar players and ask one to be made for you. You will hardly pay more than 10 bucks on such a thing.

Analog solution to a digital problem, YAY!